# Set child-src CSP in Meteor

Tags: meteor

I'm using Meteor's browser-policy packages for maintaining CSP in my app.
Recently I loaded some script from other domain that initiates a Web Worker to run some other script (blob).

Then I get the following error (latest Chrome):

```
Refused to create a child context containing 'blob:http%3A//localhost%3A3000/6057c8e1-a4ed-4d5e-ac97-230d5b1e99f3' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' ... list of all allowed domains... . Note that 'child-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

How can I set `child-src` for my app requests? Should I do it manually or there is any easier way to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can install the package browser-policy to solve this issue.

```
meteor add browser-policy
```

Then you can add this in your server code:

```
BrowserPolicy.content.allowOriginForAll('blob:');
```